# Line integral where $C$ is the boundary of the square -Green's Theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, greens-theorem

I am trying to solve the following problem but I face difficulties with the results. Any suggestion?

The line integral $\int_C y^2 dx - x dy$, where $C$ is the boundary of the square $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ oriented counterclockwise, can be evaluated in two ways:

a) Using the definition of the line integral:
To compute the line integral directly from its definition, we break the path $C$ into four segments corresponding to the sides of the square. For each segment, we parameterize the path, compute $dx$ and $dy$, substitute into the integral, and evaluate.

b) Using Green's theorem:
Green's theorem relates a line integral around a simple closed curve $C$ to a double integral over the plane region $D$ bounded by $C$. It states that
$\int_C P dx + Q dy = \int\int_D \left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right) dA$
where $P(x,y) = -x$ and $Q(x,y) = y^2$. We can compute the partial derivatives, substitute them into the double integral, and evaluate over the region $D$, which is the square \$[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$.

**SOLUTION**

a)
To solve the line integral $\int_C y^2 dx - x dy$ using the definition, we need to consider the path $C$ which is the boundary of the square with vertices at $(-1,-1)$, $(-1,1)$, $(1,1)$, and $(1,-1)$, oriented counterclockwise. We'll break $C$ into four segments corresponding to the sides of the square:

1. $C_1$ from $(-1,-1)$ to $(-1,1)$ where $x = -1$ and y varies from $-1$ to $1$.
2. $C_2$ from $(-1,1)$ to $(1,1)$ where $y = 1$ and $x$ varies from $-1$ to $1$.
3. $C_3$ from $(1,1)$ to $(1,-1)$ where $x = 1$ and $y$ varies from $1$ to $-1$.
4. $C_4$ from $(1,-1)$ to $(-1,-1)$ where $y =-1$ and $x$ varies from $1$ to $-1$.

Now we'll compute the integral over each segment and sum them:

1. On $C_1$, dx = 0$ (since $x$ is constant), so the integral becomes:
   $$
   \int_{-1}^{1} -x dy = \int_{-1}^{1} -(-1) dy = \int_{-1}^{1} dy = y\Big|_{-1}^{1} = 2
   $$
2. On $C_2$, $dy = 0$ (since $y$ is constant), so the integral becomes:
   $$
      \int_{-1}^{1} y^2 dx = \int_{-1}^{1} 1^2 dx = \int_{-1}^{1} dx = x\Big|_{-1}^{1} = 2
      $$
3. On $C_3$, similar to $C_1$, $dx = 0$, so the integral becomes:
   $$
      \int_{1}^{-1} -x dy = \int_{1}^{-1} -(1) dy = \int_{-1}^{1} dy = y\Big|_{-1}^{1}  = 2
      $$
4. On $C_4$,  so the integral becomes:
   $$
      \int_{1}^{-1} y^2 dx = \int_{1}^{-1} (-1)^2 dx = -\int_{-1}^{1} dx = -x\Big|_{-1}^{1}  = -2
      $$

Therefore, the total integral around $C$ is $2 + 2 + 2 -2 = 4$.

b)To correctly apply Green's Theorem for the line integral around the boundary $C $ of the square $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$, we need to consider the functions $ P $ and $ Q $ as given in the integral:

[
\int_C y^2 dx - x dy
]

Here, $ P(x, y) = y^2 $ and $ Q(x, y) = -x $. According to Green's Theorem, the line integral over the closed curve $ C $ can be transformed into a double integral over the region $ R $ enclosed by $ C $:

$$
\oint_C P\,dx + Q\,dy = \iint_R \left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right) dA
$$

First, we calculate the partial derivatives of $ P$ and $ Q $:

- $$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial (-x)}{\partial x} = -1$$
- $$(\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial (y^2)}{\partial y} = 2y$$

So, the double integral becomes:

$$
\iint_R (-1 - 2y) dA
$$

The region $ R $ is the square $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$, thus the integral is over $ x $ from $-1$ to $1$ and $ y $ from $-1$ to $1$.

Calculating the double integral:

$$
\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} (-1 - 2y) dx dy=-4$$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @KurtG. Why do I get different results?

Comment: Only the sign is different. You wrote correctly that line integration has to be counterclockwise but you integrated clockwise.

Comment: @KurtG.  oh ok! Thank you